# How to use mariadb connector J to Aurora in real world?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, jdbc, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I'm few years experience DBA and doing some test to Aurora for MySQL compat. Because I do not have experience developing apps, I wanna ask how to use mariadb connecotor J.

In my research, when client want to connect to writer node, coding before execute query,conn.setReadOnly(false). On the other hand, to reader node setReadOnly(true).Is it correct?? I really appreciate if I get just quick answer. Thanks.

Comment: Your understanding sounds correct. What is the exact issue you are facing?

Comment: Wow, so quick...!  I just wrote test code like, conn.setReadOnly(false) conn.execute(SELECT @@innodb_read_only), setReadOnly(true) conn.execute(SELECT @@innodb_read_only). Then manually do failover to Aurora cluster, and its result was kinda different what I was thinking. It seems that after failver, get innodb_read_only=false on both conn.execute query few secounds... and I wonder my code is correct before deep research.

Comment: This was because Aurora reader instance restarts and old writer restart after new writer promoted when failover executes. Solved.Thanks.